# Format Drive in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm attempting to make a Python 3.3 program to format a drive in Windows such as a SD Card or USB Stick. I tried the code here: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/537724-formatting-device-script-windows. At first it gave me an error, but after some tweaking it didn't. It ran but nothing happened to my USB Drive. Here's the code I'm using. (This is using the ctypes module btw) Please Help!

```
def myFmtCallback(command, modifier, arg):
    print(command)
    return 1    # TRUE

def format_drive(Drive, Format, Title):
    fm = windll.LoadLibrary('fmifs.dll')
    FMT_CB_FUNC = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, c_void_p)
    FMIFS_HARDDISK = 0x0C
    fm.FormatEx(c_wchar_p(Drive), FMIFS_HARDDISK, c_wchar_p(Format),
                c_wchar_p(Title), True, c_int(0), FMT_CB_FUNC(myFmtCallback))
```

I call the function accordingly:

```
format_drive('F:\\', 'NTFS', 'USBDrive')
```

And the program prints this:

```
>>>
9
11
```

Comment: How did you use your function? How do you pass (and which) arguments to the functions?

Comment: be careful with this one.

Comment: Be careful with what?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the argument, but the callback prints this when the program runs: >>> 

9
11

Comment: @Luke: `myFmtCallback` is passed three parameters: the command, the modifier, and the argument. Print the command *and* the argument. Maybe the modifier too. The argument gives additional information, like whether it failed or not.

Comment: I am only using the code I found somewhere else. The `myFmtCallback` function is only called here: `FMT_CB_FUNC(myFmtCallback))`

Comment: You can see all the code i'm using above by the way. Also for the myFmtCallback fuction

Comment: Ok! I found the solution! In the line: `FMIFS_HARDDISK = 0x0C`, the `0x0C` should be in text form (quotations). Thanks for the help! (Stupid Mistake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! This line:

```
 FMIFS_HARDDISK = 0x0C
```

should be like this

```
 FMIFS_UNKNOWN = 0
```

That simply makes it format by Unknown!

Comment: I tried it with `0xB` and it worked but it took longer. What is the advantage of this again?

Comment: The advantage is that using a string is wrong, and it only works because it defaults to `Unknown` (0). Either intentionally use `Unknown` to let the system figure out the media type, or provide the right media type -- either `RemoveableMedia` (11) or `FixedMedia` (12).

Comment: Well it will be unknown either way, because the program is for distribution. That said, would `0xC` or `0xB` be preferable? Or possibly just unknown?

Comment: For the unformatted drive `F:`, what do you get for [`windll.kernel32.GetDriveTypeW('F:\\')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Probably `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` (2).

Answer (score 0):

I've looked long and hard for documentation of the windows calls, I could not find anything on Microsoft that matched how FormatEx is called here.

Finally I've found this: http://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d85/fmifs_8h_source.html

Here you can find how to set the cluster size for example.