# Filling a USB with 0 bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, usb, byte

I'm writing a program that will fill a USB drive with 0 bytes in order to turn it into a bootable disk (that part is coming later).

Right now what I have is this:

```
import io
import lib


class CancelBlockCipherException(Exception): pass


class Formatter(object):

    def __init__(self, usb):
        self.usb = usb

    def _erase_all(self, block_cipher):
        with io.FileIO(self.usb, "w") as _usb:
            while _usb.write(block_cipher): pass

    def format_usb(self, size, default="y"):
        block_cipher = b"\0" * size
        confirmation = lib.settings.prompt(
            "Your USB is about to be completely erased, everything on this "
            "drive will be gone, are you sure you want to continue", "y/N(default '{}')".format(default)
        )
        if confirmation.lower().startswith("y") or confirmation == "":
            lib.settings.LOGGER.warning("Erasing USB content..")
            self._erase_all(block_cipher)
        elif confirmation.lower() == "" or confirmation is None:
            lib.settings.LOGGER.warning("Erasing USB content..")
            self._erase_all(block_cipher)
        else:
            raise CancelBlockCipherException("User aborted block cipher.")
```

What this will do is take the size of the USB in bytes, and write `\0` to `/dev/sdb1` until it has completely filled the USB file with 0 bytes (at least that's what I think is happening, I've been wrong before.) What I would like to do is make this write to the file faster. Right now this can take anywhere from 10-15 minutes to complete, because writing `\0` 1,875,615,744(1.75GB) times will probably take up a lot of time. How can I successfully format this USB, more efficiently and quicker, using pure python?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568706/format-drive-in-python

Comment: @JoshuaNixon I'm not implementing Windows yet, but I'll save that for later, thank you

Answer (score 0):

A really messy way would be to hard-code, for example, a million copies of `\0` into the code, and just write that to the disk for as long as it takes? I'm not sure if that will drastically reduce the time.