# How to format a hard drive in Python on WIndows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winapi

I am looking for a way to format a hard drive by given letter, desired volume serial number (VSN) and file system type. I found this [Format Drive in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568706/format-drive-in-python) but it's said nothing and setting VSN, and as far as I understand it's done asynchroniously.

```
letter = "H:"
vsn = "A78B-12BF"  # or 1745221157
fstype = "FAT32"

format_drive(letter, vsn, fstype)  # <-- what should be here?
```

I need a solution for Python 3 on Windows.

Comment: if use *c/c++* you can call `GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryW(L"fmifs"), "FormatEx")` this api have signature `BOOL WINAPI FormatEx(PCWSTR DosPath, MEDIA_TYPE Type, PCWSTR FileSystemName, 
   PCWSTR VolumeLabel, BOOLEAN QuickFormat, DWORD SectorSize, BOOLEAN (CALLBACK* cb)(DWORD a, DWORD , PBOOLEAN ))`

Comment: and call it as `FormatEx(L"H:", FixedMedia, L"FAT32", L"A78B-12BF", TRUE, 0, cb);` where callback - `BOOLEAN CALLBACK cb(DWORD a, DWORD , PBOOLEAN pb)`

Comment: @RbMm It looks nice. Could you, please, provide an extended answer for Python below?

Comment: i don't know python. this `fmifs.FormatEx` called by explrore when we select format drive

Comment: @RbMm I tried your solution. The 4th argument of FormatEx is not VSN, it's actually the title of the partition. The function `FormatEx` generates a random VNS if it's called as you wrote. So it doesn't suitable to me.

Comment: 4th argument is volume label - optional string(can be 0)

Comment: Yes, but I need a way to specify a certain volume serial number.